# rewrite rule is not redirecting properly

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to be able to use rewrite rules to redirect anyone who opens the link :

```
 domain.com/name
```

to

```
 index.php?username=name
```

what would be the best way to do it?

I tried to post the htaccess code I wrote but stackoverflow keeps saying it doesn't meet standards so I removed it.
thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean "index.php?username=name"

Comment: yes. fixed it sorry. its actually like this : index.php?a=profile&u=johndoe

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  index.php?username=%1   [L,QSA]
```

It will map silently

`http://domain.com/name`

To

`http://domain.com/index.php?username=name`

For this to work, `/name` must be the first directory in the incoming URL path.

Comment: Might be nice to use QSA (query-string append) option on that RewriteRule so other GET parameters are passed through.

Comment: @Wivlaro Agree. Thanks. I did not include it because the question looks very specific, but it doesn't hurt. Thanks again.

Comment: now if I go to domain.com then the site breaks and says : no username found

Comment: it returns an error saying no username found as if its not passing the %1. do I have to change it to $1 ?

Comment: No. Please copy-paste in a comment the complete URL you entered in the browser's address bar to have an idea of what's the problem.

Comment: @fogsy I don't think the error you are getting `no username found` is a  redirection error, but an error from the script that GET the parameter.